# Couchbase - Elasticsearch - transport. Mapping to types

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase, elasticsearch-plugin

I have next problem:

I have bucket in *couchbase* - named **cars**.
I Have index in *elasticsearch* - named **test**

I mapped my document.
In **elasticsearch** config i set:

```
couchbase.typeSelector.defaultDocumentType: 'Test'
couchbase.typeSelector.documentTypeDelimiter: '_'
```

I started replication from *couchbase* to *elasticsearch*.
**BUT! All my documents going to default type** (**Test**)

I also tried mapping with **doc.NameOfProperty** - but it doesn't help me :(

I don't have idea why it doesn't work.

My target - set documents from couchbase to elasticsearch by **TYPE**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the document type selector setting. By default the plugin uses the `DefaultTypeSelector`, which just assigns all documents to the defaultDocumentType, which in your case is "Test".

To have the plugin assign documents to types by splitting the id according to a delimiter, you need to tell the plugin to use the `DelimiterTypeSelector`. Add the following line to your elasticsearch.yml to go with what you already have in your config:

```
couchbase.typeSelector: org.elasticsearch.transport.couchbase.capi.DelimiterTypeSelector
```

This way the plugin will assign any documents with ids in the form of "Something_123" to the type "Something" and all other documents to the type "Test".

Your total couchbase related settings should look something like this:

```
couchbase.username: Administrator
couchbase.password: 12345 # Same as the combination on my luggage
couchbase.ignoreFailures: true
couchbase.wrapCounters: true
couchbase.ignoreDotIndexes: true
couchbase.typeSelector: org.elasticsearch.transport.couchbase.capi.DelimiterTypeSelector
couchbase.typeSelector.documentTypeDelimiter: '_'
couchbase.typeSelector.defaultDocumentType: 'Test'
```

Comment: Thanks David. This world so small)))))))